# upgrade cakephp from 2.3 to 2.5

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem with some code and I found out that I have an older version of cakephp installed on the server I am using which is ver 2.3. I want to upgrade this version from 2.3 to cakephp ver 2.5 .I need to:

1) place new version in the lib/cake folder (overwrite?)

2) check migration guide for any function differences.

The advice given here was to simply refer to the migration guide but this guide says nothing about installing and mentions only  upgrading from 2.4 which I don't even have?
I don't want a potential headache moving from 2.3 to 2.5.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-5-migration-guide.html

Comment: Also look at https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-upgrade

Comment: What's your server set up? Are there many cakephp sites on the same server, sharing the same version of Cake? Is there only 1 CakePHP site on the server?

Comment: I had to do the same thing. I did this using beyond compare program. (bad thing is that, it is not free software, but u can check maybe it will give some trial period). I Opened an empty cake 2.5 folder in the left and my current 2.3 on the right. copied all files that were manually created, like controllers, components, models, behaviors, views, helpers, css, js folders of webroot. And mainly that is it. Be careful to not replace the index.php file in webroot directory, as well as htaccess files. For files that exist in both sides, open a new tab and compare manually.

Comment: This is a dedicated server . Seems like I could just upload caek2.5 and copy existing files and see what happens

Comment: yep, you could do that.

Comment: Some of the worst docs I've seen. Migration __guide__ isn't a guide but a list of features added and deprecated -- useless. What are the steps to migrate???